# Angularjs Digest Cycle lock scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Good afternoon guys,

I have the following problem I have a navigation tab on the same screen that reference the four section in html. These sections gain display block or display none according to the active tab, and each tab has a different content that is already loaded in the background via ajax, until the ai everything works the problem is when I navigate between tabs have boxes with different sizes of Height, apparently the cycle of digestion of Angularjs takes to recognize this resizing and the scroll of the page is locked until it detects the new height, somebody has any idea of ​​how I can proceed to solve this, I am using IONIC FRAMEWORK.

Below is an image that shows how the content boxes are, remembering that only one is visible at a time, and when I looked at the page I noticed that the locking occurs in the `style =" transform: translate3d (0px, 0px, 0px) Scale (1);`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a few attempts I left this bug aside and went to other functions and when making a correction in the directive that controls the tabs I noticed that I could recalculate the scroll size as soon as a new tab was loaded added the following line click function:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.resize(); //Fix box resize bug when trasition between tabs
```

The function go be so:

```
  $timeout(function () {
    childElem = angular.element(document.querySelector(".child")).prop('children');
    if(childElem.length){
      for (var i = 0; i < childElem.length; i++) {
        angular.element(childElem[i]).on('click', function (e) {
          var tab = angular.element(e.path ? e.path[0] : e.target).prop('id').replace(/tab/g, "");
          $rootScope.$emit('aba_ativa_feed', tab); // informa a view feed qual a aba ativa
          for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            if(i == tab - 1) {
              ativos[i] = true;
            } else {
              ativos[i] = false;
              angular.element(document.querySelector("#tab-nav-block-id-".concat(i+1))).addClass('ng-hide');
            }
          }
          angular.element(document.querySelector("#tab-nav-block-id-".concat(tab))).removeClass('ng-hide');
          $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(0, blocksScrollPosition[tab - 1], true);
          scope.active = ativos;
          scope.$apply();
          $ionicScrollDelegate.resize(); //Fix box resize bug when trasition between tabs
        })
      }
    }
  }, 200)
```

for more details look [here](https://github.com/1fabiopereira/ionic-tab-nav-bar)